# Using Intel QSV in WSL2

Tags: linux, windows, ffmpeg

I want to use Intel QSV in WSL2.

Based on the experience of using QSV on a native Ubuntu PC, I installed the same library, but it doesn't work.

ex) ffmpeg, libva, vainfo, intel Media SDK, gmmlib, media-driver ...

My CPU supports QSV, but I can't initialize it.

In vainfo it works like this:

```
$ ls /dev/dri
card0 renderD128

$ sudo vainfo
Trying display: wayland
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Trying display: x11
libva info: VA-API version 1.16.0
libva info: User environment variable requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
Assuming 131072kB available aperture size.
May lead to reduced performance or incorrect rendering.
get chip id failed: -1 [22]
param: 4, val: 0
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 18
vaInitialize failed with error code 18 (invalid parameter),exit
```

I want WSL to be initialized properly so I can use it in C.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the libva driver to i965 if it solves the error, Your error logs shows the call to i965 driver instead of iHD.

```
DRM_IOCTL_I915_GEM_APERTURE failed: Invalid argument
```

export LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME="i965"
export LIBVA_DRIVER_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri"

Please make sure that the shared object files already exists in this path.

for more information you can visit. https://github.com/intel/media-driver/issues/195